# Location Manager not displaying Allow permission

Tags: ios, gps, location

I'm a novice programmer, trying to get Location Manager to work. To start with I think I need the "Allow permission to use location" box to come up. I have imported CoreLocation, set locationManager as delegate, set desired accuracy to Best, and set startUpdatingLocation. I have also added text to the Info.plist for Privacy - Location Usage Description. According to the Apple iOS Developer library this is all I need to do. I'm thinking that once I get the Allow Permission box up and click Allow, then I can start adding code to work with the GPS position. Using Xcode 8.3. 
P.S. is it ok to put my code on here?

Comment: Yeah a code example is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you have to request the use of location services as stated in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW62

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking authorization status (as per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW72)):

```
- (BOOL)checkLocationServicesAuthorizationStatus
{
    switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus])
    {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            [self requestLocationServicesUseAuthorization];
            return NO;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
            return YES;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        default:
            return NO;
    }
}
```

First time users will have an undetermined status so you need to request the proper authorization:

```
- (void)requestLocationServicesUseAuthorization NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)
{
#if LOCATION_ALWAYS_REQUIRED
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
#else
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
#endif
}
```

The delegate callback is handy to start updating the location after they accept the permissions dialog:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{   
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && [self checkLocationServicesAuthorizationStatus])
    {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

The [`+locationServicesEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled) class method on `CLLocationManager` should also be checked to make sure that location services are enabled in the first place.